# wxPython で Sizer の設定が反映されない

Tags: python, python3

以下のコードにてsizerを使用したいのですがどのようにすれば適切にsizerが反映されますか？
FrameクラスとPanelクラスで分けてあります。
Panelクラスの中にrpanelというpanelを作成してその上にbotton1とcalendの２つを表示させています。
表示まではうまくいくのですがSizerを使用してレイアウトをしてもずっと２つとも（0，0）固定で設定したsizerが反映されないです。

動いてほしい挙動としてはrpanelをSizerを利用して横に二分割し、上に' ＜　'のボタンが、その下にcalendが表示される形にしたいと思っています。また、calendに関してはrpanelの横目いっぱいに広がって、Frameの動きに追従する形にしたいです。

```py
class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("#618264")

        rpanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=(500,500))
        rpanel.SetBackgroundColour("#79AC78")


        button1 = buttons.GenButton(rpanel, -1, '　＜　', style=wx.BORDER_NONE)

        calend = wx.lib.calendar.Calendar(rpanel, wx.ID_ANY,)　#size=(500,400))
        calend.SetCurrentDay()
        calend.HideTitle()
        calend.HideGrid()
        calend.SetWeekColor( ("#000000"), ("#79AC78"))
        calend.SetBusType()
        layout = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=2, cols=1, gap=(10, 10))　
        layout.Add(butoon1, 1, wx.Grow)
        layout.Add(calend, 2, wx.Grow)
        rpanel.SetSizer(layout)
```

完成形のイメージとしてはこの図のような形です。MenuとStatusBarはFrameクラスで記述済みです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panelの中に`rpanel`がレイアウトされていないことが主な原因です。
Panelを横に二分割して左側に`rpanel`を配置したいので、Panel自体に`wx.GridSizer`を`SetSizer`で適用してください。

下記のサンプルコードでは[`SetSizerAndFit`](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Window.html?highlight=setsizerandfit#wx.Window.SetSizerAndFit)を使用してサイズを最適化しています。

**サンプルコード**

```
import wx, wx.lib.calendar
from wx.lib import buttons

class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("#618264")

        rpanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=(500,500))
        rpanel.SetBackgroundColour("#79AC78")

        button1 = buttons.GenButton(rpanel, -1, '　＜　＞　', style=wx.BORDER_NONE)
        calend = wx.lib.calendar.Calendar(rpanel, wx.ID_ANY)
        calend.SetCurrentDay()
        calend.HideTitle()
        calend.HideGrid()
        calend.SetWeekColor( ("#000000"), ("#79AC78"))
        calend.SetBusType()

        layout = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=2, cols=1, gap=(10, 10))
        layout.Add(button1, proportion=wx.GROW, flag=wx.EXPAND) # ボタンを横にExpandする
        layout.Add(calend, wx.GROW, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        rpanel.SetSizerAndFit(layout)
        self_layout = wx.GridSizer(rows=1, cols=2, gap=(0, 0))
        self_layout.Add(rpanel)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self_layout)  # Panel自体にwx.GridSizerを適用
        parent.Fit() # Frameのサイズを最適にする

application = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, 'テストフレーム')
menu_bar = wx.MenuBar()
menu_bar.Append(wx.Menu(), 'ファイル')
frame.SetMenuBar(menu_bar)
frame.CreateStatusBar()
frame.SetStatusText('Hello, Sizer!')

panel = Panel(frame)

frame.Show()
application.MainLoop()
```

**実行結果**

[image: 実行結果]